# C++ Exception:Throwing Arrays and getting array size in catch

Tags: c++, arrays, exception

A Normal function ( say printArray) takes array and its size ( 2 arguments ) to print elements of an array.

How to do the same using exceptions? More exactly, how to pass array size to catch handler ? ( assuming I dont have a const int SIZE declared outside try-catch)
eg.

```
 //void printArray(int* foo ,int size);
     int foo[] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
   //printArray(foo,5); //OK, function call using array accepts size=5 
    try{

        //do something
        throw foo;

    }
    catch (int* pa)
    {
        //I have to get array size to loop through and print array values
        //    How to get array size?
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the function takes array why inside try block have you initialized it? int foo[] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };

Comment: Throw a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Ashot - sorry ,  Assume int foo[] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 }; lies in line before try {.  I edited code above.         Thanks Jerry , yes vector does work, but I am interested to know if its possible to get array size using basic c++ array

Comment: Note that if the catch handler is in another function than the array, and the array is a local non-static variable, then stack unwinding will have destroyed the array before you reach the handler. If the array is in the same function, you should know the size anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can throw both array and it's size as a pair in the following way:

```
throw std::make_pair(foo, 5);
```

and get these two values like this:

```
catch(std::pair<int*, int>& ex)
{
...
}
```

Comment: In the `catch` you want angle brackets.

Comment: You also need to remember a typical way of determining a fixed-array size is via `sizeof foo/sizeof *foo`. When used as your second arg to `std::make_pair`, will *not* be `int`, and thus not qualify for your catch. Not that you can do anything with that pointer anyway if the array is declared in the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments.                                             pair example works ( probably will use when using arr on heap, and when thrown , caught on calling function ).         celtschk ref, was very helpful . I will use this info for local non static array on same scope

```
int main()
{
    int foo[] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
    int size = sizeof(foo)/ sizeof(int);
    try{
        //throw foo;
        throw (pair<int*,int>(foo,size));
    }
    catch (int* foo)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << foo[i] << ",";
    }
    catch (pair<int*, int>& ip)
    {
        cout << "pair.." << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < ip.second; i++)
            cout << ip.first[i] << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```